# What does "Get a bearing on" mean?

Tags: terminology

In *Top Gun* (1986), a flight got hit by a missile:

> Airboss: **Get a bearing on** Hollywood and Wolfman
> and launch the rescue helicopter immediately.

What does "Get a bearing on" mean?

Comment: Just another word for *Direction to...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to obtain a magnetic bearing from the ship to the location where the survivors ejected in order to get the helicopter flying in the correct direction expeditiously.

This would entail plotting a point that is 090 degrees for 20 miles from the "bullseye" briefed for that mission, marking that spot, and plotting a bearing line from the ship to that point.

See the answer to this question to understand the second paragraph above:  ["090 for 20"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95898/what-does-zero-for-twenty-mean)